# How do I make query faster with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, game-engine

I have a problem with the time to query my database with PHP. I recently started creating an MMO RPG ONLINE using the program *engine001*, I also use PHP and MySQL to query info of my database but it takes too long to make a query (it usually takes one sec to query).

Steps:

1. First of all I query a webpage of my website which has the .php file (site.com/file.php)
2. This php file, will query into my database
3. This is printed (echo) at the page so my game pick the value e then make whatever it wants.

Here we have an example, this PHP file will send the new position of an actor:

```
include("mysqlconfig.inc");

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$positionX = $_REQUEST['positionX'];
$positionY = $_REQUEST['positionY'];
$query = "UPDATE players SET positionX = '$positionX',positionY = '$positionY' WHERE ID = $id ";

$res = mysql_query($query);


mysql_close($con);
```

I have no idea how online games are made and *why* they are so fast but this is how I do mine. It's the only way I figured out how to do that.

My question is, is there any way to make it a little bit faster?

Comment: Maybe you can look in to how facebook did this all. (just something that slide into my head).

Comment: Check this post on gamedev: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/what-kind-of-databases-are-usually-used-in-an-mmorpg. I don't know what kind of hardware you're running, but it might be too much for your server to run those kinds of constant requests in a relational db. Maybe try MonogoDB?

Comment: CouchDB for the win...

Comment: Sure; `http://example.com?positionX=42'); DROP TABLE players; --`. Without players, your system will be REALLY fast. In other words you're wide open for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and can expect your game to be destroyed within minutes.

Comment: Yeah that is another problem, but if I just use a _POST instead of _REQUEST should it be a little bit more secure?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this approach will ever be fast enough for a real time game. As you have discovered, making database queries for things like player positions is far too slow. Real time games do not typically use web-based backends because HTTP is a stateless protocol, but you need to have the game state persist in the process's memory to make it fast enough. So you will probably have to look at writing the backend as a custom server using sockets.

Comment: That was my fear D: Damn Thx I guess I have to study more about all this. D: I forgot to put the game for you guys can test: [DropBox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b07263sawdhpb3k/RPG%20Online%20Setup%201.0.rar)